# how to get value from dynamic radiobutton in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, datatables

i want ask somethink after i get some problem in my code.
so.. first i'm making a survey with input radiobutton in datatables down there is the code
**EDIT**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
   $('#example').DataTable({
       "paging": true,
       "searching": false,
       "bInfo": false,
       "bLengthChange": false,
       "pageLength": 2
   });
   
    // $('#save').click(function(){
    //         var radioValue = $(".circle:checked").val();
    //         // if(radioValue){
    //         //     alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
    //         // }
    //         console.log(radioValue)
    //     });
        

   
$('#save').click(function() {
    var the_value;
    //the_value = jQuery('input:radio:checked').val();
    //the_value = jQuery('input[name=macro]:radio:checked').val();
    the_value = getChecklistItems();
    alert(the_value);
});

function getChecklistItems() {
    var result = 
       $("tr.checklisttr > td > input:radio:checked").get();

        console.log(result)
    
    var columns = $.map(result, function(element) {
        return $(element).attr("id");
    });

    return columns.join("|");
}
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="datatables@1.10.12" data-semver="1.10.12" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="datatables@1.10.12" data-semver="1.10.12" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <style> 
    .circle{
        color:blue;
    }
  </style>
   
    <form action="" name="quiz" id="quiz_form" method="post">
   <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead style="font-size:20px">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Nomor</th>
        <th colspan="4"><center>Test</center></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="display: none;"></th>
         <th style="display: none;"></th>
          <th style="display: none;"></th>

          <th style="display: none;"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-size:18px">
          
            <tr class="checklisttr" id="1">
                
                <td align="left" width="40%"><br>
                    <label for="veryiii" style="align:left;">1</label>
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%">
                    <input type="radio" id="vii1" name="om" value="4.5"  class="circle">Good
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%">
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="veryiii1" name="om" value="3.0" class="circle"> Noermal
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%">
                    <input type="radio" id="viv1" name="om" value="1.5"  class="circle">Bad
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%">
                
                    <input type="radio" id="veryv1" name="om" value="1.0" class="circle">Verry Bad
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr class="checklisttr" id="2">
                
                <td align="left" width="40%">
                    <label for="veryiii" style="align:left;">2</label>
                </td>
      
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="vii1" name="om1" value="4.5" class="circle">Good
                </td>
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="veryiii1" name="om1" value="3.0" class="circle">Normal 
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="viv1" name="om1" value="1.5" class="circle">Bad
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="veryv1" name="om1" value="1.0" class="circle">Very Bad
                </td>
            </tr>
          
              <tr class="checklisttr" id="3">
                
                <td align="left" width="40%">
                    <label for="veryiii" style="align:left;">3</label>
                </td>
  
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="vii1" name="om2" value="4.5" class="circle">Good
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="veryiii1" name="om2" value="3.0" class="circle"> Normal
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="viv1" name="om2" value="1.5" class="circle">Bad
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" width="12%"><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="veryv1" name="om2" value="1.0" class="circle">Very Bad
                </td>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

        <div class="pull-right">
              <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-pencil5"></i> Done</button>
        </div>
</form>
 
  </body>

</html>
```

if you trying to answear the questions and click done why the answear just show the last data?

i just want to get all value and why if i go to next page for answear the next question and i submit form why he not show all the value, so how to get all data after answear all the question?? thanks

Comment: you are using radios wrong , only one should be selected from each row, or else use checkbox, and use name and use same name for all radios in one row, like maybe, question1 ,question2 ,

Comment: ups sorry i just want to edit this questions

Comment: i see the problem, you are using datatable with pagination, if you inspect it,  you will see it removes the tr when you change page, so when you click on save  the form has only current visible inpputs

Comment: yeah thats right, i make the question with DataTable because If the question data exceeds one hundred I want to be made into more than one page then I use DataTables and use pagination for the next question and answer the question. or is there any other way besides using data table to display question like appearance as above?